# Why can't I enter the wordpress admin interface?

Tags: php, wp-admin, cookies

I accidentally changed the url of my wordpress page, which I finally managed to restore in phpmyadmin, the first page of my website works, but the second page doesn't, and I can't even log in to the admin interface because it throws this error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: setcookie(): "path" option cannot contain ",", ";", " ", "\t", "\r", "\n", "\013", or "\014" in C:\xampp\htdocs\hh\wp-login.php:481 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\hh\wp-login.php(481): setcookie('wordpress_test_...', 'WP Cookie check', 0, '/hh\r\n/', '', false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\hh\wp-login.php on line 481 This is the part of the code: if ( SITECOOKIEPATH !== COOKIEPATH ) { setcookie( TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure ); }

I looked to see if I had hit something there, but no. I've also tried to replace it with a code copied from github, but that doesn't work either. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The error message you see points to this part within the wp-login.php file:

```
setcookie( TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );
```

to its "path", which is the 4th parameter:

```
SITECOOKIEPATH
```

If you check how that constant is defined, that is:

```
define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', preg_replace( '|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option( 'siteurl' ) . '/' ) );
```

meaning the "siteurl" option of WordPress defines it, which would come from your admin area Settings -> General -> WordPress Address (URL). This is stored within the `[prefix]_options` database table, so that is where you should try to fix your url: `option_name` -> `siteurl`